# Why is Audio such an issue in HTML5 Games and how soon will it be corrected?

Tags: html, audio, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I am interested in using HTML5 canvas to develop games and have even used the  Construct 2 Game engine to create games. I noticed that everything works fine until you put in audio. I used ogg format then.

Now that I am trying to learn HTML5 Canvas game creation, I am being told that the same problem arises in this as well. I visited the following site:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/

I would like to tell you why I would like to get into the field. It is because I think this may have a great influence in the ad market if this really kicks off. But the audio problem can be a hindrance in this.

So why is audio such a problem as video itself is more complex and will it be sorted out anytime soon?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that different browsers support different types of audio files as shown on this website http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

This is mainly due to the lack of regulations and standards surrounding HTML 5, users and developers may find it difficult to support all audio formats on all browsers.

I've read somewhere that you can add in different audio formats and if one fails, it will play the other format but I can't find the link again. Sorry :(

Good Luck